# PWA - detect when the app returns from the background?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to detect that the the user just returned to the app after leaving it to another app and then back? I tried to use `window.onfocus` but it only worked in a PC browser.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you may utilize [Page Visibility API](https://whatwebcando.today/foreground-detection.html). Listen for `visibilitychange` event and check `document.hidden` property there.

Comment: The event is also fired when the page is reloaded btw